# AccountController in Microsoft Identity on Blazor change endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying change endpoints, and default pagaes of Microsoft Identity autentication in Blazor Project with azureB2C authentication.
I got two endpoints:

- `MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn`
- `MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut`

I want to change this on for e.g. `account/SignOut`.

After sign out, browser redirect to `MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut`, I want to change this rule.

I was trying create my own AccountController.cs but it's not work. I don't know, how can I use my own AccountController in this case,because Microsoft docs, don't explain this.

I discovered that, when I create file `SignedOut.cshtml` in `Area.MicrosoftIdentity.Pages.Account`, I can change view of default pages. But I get error about conflict

`"warning CS0436: The type 'Areas_MicrosoftIdentity_Pages_Account_SignedOut'...."`

I don't know what should I do. Sorry for my English, I'm still learning.